# Sum of cost IF checkbox is true

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, numbers

I'm making a spreadsheet in Numbers to calculate how much deposit each tenant of a house should get based on who is responsible for particular damages; below is the sheet so far.

[image: spreadsheet]

In the "Total Bill" column I would like to have a sum of the charges, divided by the number of people involved, for all damages. Formulae I have tried previously are,

```
SUMIF(C2:C20,TRUE,B2:B20÷K2:K20)
SUMIF(person, true, cost/split)
```

This does not work however. What should I use instead?

Comment: so you want something like `{=SUM(C2:C20*B2:B20/K2:K20)}`???

Comment: Yes that is another one that I have tried, returns with "The range C2:C20 can't be used as a single value".

Comment: try `{=SUM(IF(C2:C20,B2:B20/K2:K20,0))}`.... never worked with numbers for real :P

Comment: Same error as before. Threw it at Excel to see if it was just Numbers being weird but unfortunately it didn't work on there either.

Comment: this is an array formula... you know the difference? (you need to hit ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Ah, I did not know the difference until I googled it! Sorry, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Numbers can't do math with checkboxes. Just the formula of my comment as an answer:

```
=SUM(IF(C2:C20,B2:B20/K2:K20,0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: What do you mean by "Numbers can't do math with checkboxes"? I suppose those checkboxes are *linked* to the cells, aren't they? Same question goes to you @FlamingSquirrel.

Comment: @A.S.H It looks like that `[checkbox]*3` is always 0. In excel there is no problem with the formula in your answer. Still the OP said that it always results in 0. However: I don't have any prove as i do not have access to numbers at the moment (so I cant run tests). Still, I assume that there is no fault made by the OP and it simply is not supported that way.

Comment: I am not seeking any contest at all. It's really the last of my concerns which answer was accepted :D. I just don't understand the exaplanations and certainly not why they work for this formula and not for mine. They're almost exactly the same and the sentence *"Numbers can't do math with checkboxes"* doesn't help me understand (nor for any guest reader I guess). That's all about it.

Comment: @A.S.H As said: I can't confirm anything... but having my formula going for `IF [check] then` seems to work. While `TRUE * value` is 0??? I really need to run tests ASAP because I do not understand this on my own (^o^);

Comment: Ah, that would be really weird. `TRUE * anything` well-knowingly forces Excel to convert the boolean to `0` or `1`. That doesnt' happen automatically with all functions, but surely when the boolean is operated with the operators `*, -, +, /`. IDK what's happening, but anyway, good that the question is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this **Array formula** for `Total Bill` of `Person1` then autofill (or copy/paste) under each person:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(C$2:C$20*B$2:B$20/K$2:K$20,0))
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: A good idea, but it has only returned "£0.00" even under Person 1 which _should_ be £126.25.

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel It's an **array formula**. Again, enter it then press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: Sorry I don't do an awful lot with Excel and array formula isn't supported in Numbers I have discovered. This solution does work in Excel so I've given it +1.